# Conditional assignment in pandas python based on consecutive years values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset that looks like

```
 A    B    year   CompanyName   
 1    nan  1999      tesla
 4     3   2000      tesla
 Nan  nan  2001      tesla
 2    nan  2002      tesla 
 3    nan  1999      BMW
 2    -1   2000      BMW
 2    nan  2002      BMW
```

So I have different company data and I want to calculate a new column B which is equal to the difference between the current row and the previous one of column A following these conditions:

1. the difference is done only if both consecutive years have valid values, if one year is missing then the difference should not be calculated
2. if one of the company year value of A is missing then the difference column will assume nan value
3. the difference has to be done for the same company, therefore i don't want the difference to be done for different companies

I wrote this code:

```
 finalData[~(finalData.year.diff(1).isnull()) & (finalData.year.diff(1) ==1) & 
 (finalData.companyName)]
```

but I am stuck with the companyName condition, I appreciate your time and help

Ps. I order my data based on CompanyName then year to make this strange difference

Comment: what is the expected output here? I would compute NaN for all given your data

Comment: Just updated it, I want to calculate column B based on the conditions that I wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your data is sorted by year (if not use `df = df.sort_values(by='year')`), you can do:

```
g = df.groupby('CompanyName')
df['B'] = g['A'].diff().where(df['year'].eq(g['year'].shift()+1))
```

output:

```
     A    B  year CompanyName
0  1.0  NaN  1999       tesla
1  4.0  3.0  2000       tesla
2  NaN  NaN  2001       tesla
3  2.0  NaN  2002       tesla
4  3.0  NaN  1999         BMW
5  2.0 -1.0  2000         BMW
6  2.0  NaN  2002         BMW
```

Comment: This solution violates condition 1, I just updated the data to make it more clear

Comment: @Monta check the update ;)

Comment: first of all i really thank you for the insights but I dont get why you shift the years by 2? Also Am not sure if the companyName condition is maintained

Comment: I shift the year (i.e. take the year of the previous row) and add `1` (not `2`) to check if we have a n/n+1 pattern. e.g. for BMW: 2000 == 1999+1 -> True ;  2002 == 2000+1? -> False

Comment: and the group by guarantees that we are considering the same company right?

Comment: Yes, this handles your 3 conditions ;) The only requirement is to sort by ascending dates (it's not even necessary to sort by company as the groupby will keep the subdata separated)